# onFailure never called in quarkus reactive chain

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-reactive

I have this service class where I combine two Restcalls from Service A and B to one resonse object.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ResponseHandler {

@Inject
Mapper mapper;

@Inject
ServiceA serviceA;

@Inject
ServiceB serviceB;

public Uni<Dto> handle(String id, String language) {
    return Uni.combine().all()
            .unis(serviceA.getProducts(id),
                    serviceB.getSettings(id).onFailure().recoverWithItem(SettingsResponse.builder().build()))
            .combinedWith((productsResponse, settingsResponse) -> mapper.map(productsResponse, settingsResponse, language));
}

}
```

My positive test works perfect.
But in case I mock ServiceB to throw an exception, the recover is never called and the whole chain is terminated with the expected exception:

```
Mockito.when(serviceB.getSettings(id))
                .thenThrow(new NotFoundException("Not found test"));
```

I assume I have a wrong understanding how onFailure works.... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `serviceB.getSettings()` call doesn't return a `Uni` that fails -- it directly throws an exception. Look at the stack trace of that exception -- there's nothing on the stack that could possibly catch it and transform it to a "failed `Uni`", it's just thrown too soon.

You need to arrange the mock so that it returns a `Uni` that completes with an exception. Something like `Uni.createFrom().failure(new NotFoundException("Not found test"));`.

Comment: ya that is the solution. returning exactly that solved my problem. thank you very much.

Comment: now my integration test is failing. do I need to provide a exceptionmapper to convert all kinds of exceptions to Uni Exception ???

Comment: You don't provide any information for anyone to be able to help. Maybe ask a new question?